# Need a way to divide 5 points over 2 statements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have the following 'problem'. I need a way in Angular (6) to divide 5 points over 2 statements for each question. There are 40 questions in total so 80 statements.

**Example**: If the user selects 3 points on the first statement, the second statement should automatically have only 2 points and the rest of it should be disabled or removed, though the user should be able to select a different amount of points on the first statement afterwards and the second statement should change again.

**Example image**:
[image]

Current HTML code:

```
<form [formGroup]="ratingGroup">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let questionData of questionsArr; let i = index;" formArrayName="ratings">
        <section [@visibilityChanged]="(currentQuestion == i + 1) ? 'shown' : 'hidden'" [id]="'question-' + (i + 1)">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12">

                    <p class="small">Divide 5 points over the next 2 statements<br />
                        You do not click on anything for 0 points.</p>

                </div>

                <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let question of questionData; let index = index;">
                    <p>{{ question.order }}) {{ question.text }}</p>
                    <fieldset class="rate" [formArrayName]="i">

                        <p class="float-left">Strongly disagree</p>
                        <p class="float-right">Strongly agree</p>

                        <label [for]="'rate' + ratingValue + '-' + question.id" title="Excellent" *ngFor="let ratingValue of ratingValues" [ngClass]="{blue: checker.checked}">
                            <input [id]="'rate' + ratingValue + '-' + question.id" type="radio" [name]="index"  [value]="{rating: ratingValue, type: question.type}" (change)="onChange(ratingValue, index); setBlue($event)" [formControlName]="index" #checker>
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>

                <div class="col-12">

                    <button class="back" [hidden]="currentQuestion == 1" (click)="previousQuestion()" pageScroll [href]="'#question-' + (currentQuestion - 1)">Back</button> <button (click)="nextQuestion()" pageScroll [href]="'#question-' + (currentQuestion + 1)">Next</button>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>
 </ng-container>
 </form>
```

Typescript:

```
ratingValues = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

get ratings () {
        return this.ratingGroup.get('ratings') as FormArray;
    }

    private buildForm(): void {

        this.ratingGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            ratings: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.array([
                this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]),
                this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required])
            ])])

        });

    }

    getQuestions(): void {
        this.questionService.getQuestions();

        this.questionService.getQuestions().subscribe(response => {
            let order = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if (!(i % 2)) {
                    this.questionsArr[order] = response.slice(i, i+2);
                    order++;
                    this.ratings.push(this.formBuilder.array([
                        this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]),
                        this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required])
                    ]));
                }
            }

            console.log(this.questionsArr);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using to display the 1 - 5 buttons?

Comment: can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @user184994 added the code

Comment: I can't see where `ratingValues` is set in your code, but I imagine you can modify that based on the previous selections

Comment: @user184994 Added that value to the typescript part, sorry

Comment: Also missing the `onChange` function as well...

Comment: @user184994 The `onChange` function currently has no content. Just a `console.log` with the `ratingValue` and the `element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the possible ratingValues `onChange`, so that there is never a value visible that would allow you to exceed the max.

```
total = 0;
max = 5;

onChange(ratingValue, index) {
    this.total += ratingValue;
    this.ratingValues = this.ratingValues.filter((val) => val + total <= max)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you're on the right track here, but I do need to keep all of the other values of the selected statement. So right now, if I select 5 points on the first statement, it removes all on both statements, while it should just remove it on the second one

Comment: Solved it using this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most easy and fast way to do that would be to exclude answers from an array to another.

You'll need 3 variables :

```
all: string[] = ['Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree'];
selected: string[] = [];
get available() {
  return this.all.filter(s => this.selected.some(s1 => s !== s1));
}
```

Example in Javascript :

```js
const all = ['Strongly agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Strongly disagree'];
const selected = [];
function available() {
  return selected.length ? all.filter(s => !selected.includes(s)) : [];
}

selected.push(all[0], all[2]);

console.log(selected);
console.log(available());
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(available())">Show available</button>
<div class="answers">
  
</div>
```

All you need to do is at every question, you change the value of the `selected` array. The `available` getter will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem with this one is that if the user selects for example `3`, only `3` will be excluded from the `all` array while I want to show `1` and `2`. Also, the same problem exists as the answer below, both statements will show the `available` array whilst the selected statement should show all

Comment: no, the `all` array will still contain all values. You'll have two arrays, `selected` and `available`, which respectively contains greyed and available answers. Now you can make a `*ngFor` over `all`, and a `[disabled]` over `selected` with the `Array.includes` function.

Answer (score 0):

uhmmm ... it looks like two related drop-down. Imagine you have an array of object like

```
options=[{values:[]},
 {values:[1]},
 {values[1,2]},
 {values[1,2,3]}
....]
```

you only has to make a

```
<div *ngFor="let value of options[myForm.get('control').value-1]">
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let value of [1,2,3,4,5] 
   [ngClass]="{'disabled':options[myForm.get('control').value-1].indexOf(value)<0}"
```